# how to compare the key and the value of a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to compare if the value is contained in the name in my hashmap, I want to be able to do this for all of my items in my hashmap. I have already populated my hashmap and just want to compare if if the value is contained in the name.

I currently have

```
Map<String, String> barcodeMap = Maps.newHashMap();
  while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)
   {
        barcodeMap.put(nextLine[1], nextLine[0]);
    }
```

I want to compare for example if nextLine[0] is abc and nextLine[1] is abc123, I want to compare if abc is in abc123 and if it is then make nextLine[1] abc

Comment: Define "contained in the name".

Comment: linux tag? is for something?

Comment: When saying 'name' do you mean 'key'?

Comment: A hashmap usually doesn't have a name.

Comment: What is name here??? hash map has key and value. You need to compare the value of the hashmap with its key. Say you need to check whether a key of hash map is present in the value of the same hash map??

Comment: This is how I defined my hashmap

Comment: At first look i think he is looking for Map.containsKey(). But there is quite a "name/value" confusion in this question.

Comment: It has a name, it's called Bob. Guys don't be so rude...

Comment: if you really want an answer then give an example of what you have tried so far and output showing why your attempt doesn't quite work

Comment: This is how i defined my hashmap

Map<String, String> barcodeMap = Maps.newHashMap();

Then I populated it like 

 while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

            barcodeMap.put(nextLine[1], nextLine[0]);
           

         }

Now I want to compare if nextLine[0] is contained in nextLine[1], for all the elements that I populated in my hashmap

Comment: Do you have a `Map<String, String>` and you want to find all entries where the value is a substring on the key?

Comment: yes John B that is what I want

Comment: OP, add a new question that includes this description. I have voted to reopen but don't know if it will go through.

Comment: Here is the solution: `for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()){  if (entry.getKey().contains(entry.getValue()) do something`

Comment: for example nextLine[0] is abc, and nextLine[1] is abc123, i want to see that abc is contained in abc123

Comment: @georgealbertson Update your question with the clarifications you have in the comments here and it will at least have a chance of being re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Map map = ...
for(Entry e : map.entrySet) {
     Object k = e.getKey();
     Object v = e.getValue();
     ... compare
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use containsValue() method to validate the value object present in the map.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29

```
 map.containsValue(value);
```